# Simple PS script but dirty output

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm having an issue with a script I'm writing.  The code *works* but it's not spitting out the info how I'd like to see it.  Basically, it spits it out with a few carriage returns between the final two commands.  I also tried to dump the `Get-ADUser` command into an array and then add the data from the `$Pass` into said array but that failed miserably and I could never get that to work; every which way I tried to write and execute it, would come up with errors.  Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?  If this is the way it should be done, how can I get it *cleaned up* the way I'd like it?

```
$User = Read-Host "Enter the UserName you wish to look up."

$UserInfo = Get-ADUser $User -Properties * | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, GivenName, Initials, Surname, SamAccountName, @{Name = 'Student ID'; Expression = {$_.EmployeeID}}

$Pass = '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
            $UserInfo.GivenName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
            $UserInfo.Initials[0].ToString().ToLower(),
            $UserInfo.Surname[0].ToString().ToLower(),
            $UserInfo.'Student ID')

$UserInfo | fl
Write-host "Password       : $Pass"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `$Pass` as a property just like you do with the `Student Id` property.

```
$User = Read-Host "Enter the UserName you wish to look up."

$UserInfo = Get-ADUser $User -Properties * | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, GivenName, Initials, Surname, SamAccountName, @{Name = 'Student ID'; Expression = {$_.EmployeeID}}

$Pass = '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
            $UserInfo.GivenName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
            $UserInfo.Initials[0].ToString().ToLower(),
            $UserInfo.Surname[0].ToString().ToLower(),
            $UserInfo.'Student ID')

$UserInfo | Select *,@{l='Password';e={$Pass}} | fl
```

For that matter you could do it all inline...

```
Read-Host "Enter the UserName you wish to look up." | Get-ADUser -Properties * | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, GivenName, Initials, Surname, SamAccountName, @{Name = 'Student ID'; Expression = {$_.EmployeeID}},@{l='Password';e={'{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f $_.GivenName[0].ToString().ToUpper(), $_.Initials[0].ToString().ToLower(), $_.Surname[0].ToString().ToLower(), $_.'Student ID')}} | fl
```

But that gets to be a really long line and hard to read.

To explain the line `$UserInfo | Select *,@{l='Password';e={$Pass}} | fl`, it's fairly simple. I pass the ADUser object to `Select-Object`, where I select all of the properties that it has by using the `*` wildcard, and also add a calculated property. I do use some shorter aliases, but in essence it is a hashtable where you define the name/label of the property being defined, and an expression that defines the value of it. Fully it could be:

```
@{
    label = 'Password'
    expression = {$Pass}
}
```

Since it is looking for 'label' (or 'name') as a parameter for an argument, and 'expression' for another we can shorten those to simply 'l' and 'e' as the first letter of each, which shortens the entire thing down to what you see in my code.

Comment: That certainly cleaned it up!  The one-liner failed with errors; evidently, it doesn't like all the curly braces toward the end of the line...  However, can you go into more detail about your magic line of code:  `$UserInfo | Select *,@{l='Password';e={$Pass}} | fl`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation; it was the aliases that threw me.

Comment: Been using the script a fair amount over the last week and it works well.  One issue that I keep bumping into (Someone else may run into this as well if they try to duplicate/adapt this script for their own needs.)  If the user doesn't have a middle name/initial, an error `Cannot index into a null array` will be seen and the users password will not be displayed.  However, the rest of the data will be displayed just fine.

Comment: You could use `('' + $UserInfo.Initials).ToLower()`, which should take care of that. That's two single quotes, with nothing between then, basically an empty string.

Comment: I tried your code but it spit back an error: `Cannot index into a null array.`  I worked around it with my sample below.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the bit of code that uses the format operator to compensate for the lack of a middle name/initial as noted in one of my comments.  I hope it helps someone, should they ever need it.

```
# This attempts to format the password according to our convention.
IF([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($UserInfo.Initials)) {
    $Pass = '{0}{1}#{2}' -f @(
            $UserInfo.GivenName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
            $UserInfo.Surname[0].ToString().ToLower(),
            $UserInfo.'Student ID')
    } Else {
    $Pass = '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
            $UserInfo.GivenName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
            $UserInfo.Initials[0].ToString().ToLower(),
            $UserInfo.Surname[0].ToString().ToLower(),
            $UserInfo.'Student ID')
    }
```