# Trying to create a variable with the format operator but the data for the variable changes

Tags: arrays, variables, active-directory, powershell-5.0

So, I'm back to working on a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46941382/1286501) I was playing with a while back.  It has changed a lot since its conception.  But, it still basically pulls data from a CSV and creates the accounts in AD as needed.  It worked pretty well but I ran into trouble when we noticed we had people without middle names.  The middle initial is part of our password format.  So, I've tried a few things, including recycling some of my [other code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47582009/1286501), but I cannot seem to get the AD account created with the proper password.  The account gets created but I can never authenticate with the creds the account should accept.

I've added what I feel is the relevant code.  It's not the whole script as that is 200+ lines and seems to function fine but, if you want to see it all, let me know and I'll edit the following snippet.

**The code-snippet that *works* so long as the kid has a middle initial:**

```
    # CSV file being imported.
$CsvFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\SampleData.csv"

# Import the contents of the CSV file.
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile"

# Loop through each line of the CSV, creating the user if the account doesn't already exist in AD.
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    [String]$LoginName = $User.'Stu Access Login'
    If (-Not (Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $LoginName})) {
        $FirstName = $User.'Student First Name'
        $LastName = $User.'Student Last Name'
        $ADUserParams = @{
            Name = "$FirstName $LastName"
            SamAccountName = $LoginName
            GivenName = $FirstName
            Initials = $User.'I'
            Surname = $LastName
            DisplayName = "$FirstName $($User.'I') $LastName"
            Description= $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name
            ScriptPath= "student.bat"
            UserPrincipalName = "$LoginName@academic.mydomain.k12.pa.us"
            EmailAddress = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            Company = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            EmployeeID = $User.'Other ID'
            HomeDirectory = "$FileServer\$LoginName"
            HomeDrive = "Z:"
            AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (
                '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
                    $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                    $User.I[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force
            Enabled = $True
            PasswordNeverExpires = $True
            CannotChangePassword = $True
            Path = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=mydomain,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                $User.'Grad Year',
                $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name)
            Server = $ADServer
            WhatIf = $False
        } # End ADUserParams

        Try {
            # Create new user.
            New-ADUser @ADUserParams -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write the error to the event log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName $EventLogName -Source $EventLogSources[0][1] -EntryType Warning -EventId $EventLogSources[0][0] -Message "Something went wrong with the creation of a new user, [$LoginName] : $_"
        }}}
```

***First* attempt to get around the missing middle initial:**

```
# CSV file being imported.
$CsvFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\SampleData.csv"

# Import the contents of the CSV file.
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile"

# Loop through each line of the CSV, creating the user if the account doesn't already exist in AD.
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    [String]$LoginName = $User.'Stu Access Login'
    If (-Not (Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $LoginName})) {
        # Attempt #1 for Dealing with passwords for people without a middle initial.
        IF([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($User.I)) {
            $AccountPass = '{0}{1}#{2}' -f @(
                $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                $User.'Other ID')
            } Else {
            $AccountPass = '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
                $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                $User.I[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                $User.'Other ID')
            }
        $FirstName = $User.'Student First Name'
        $LastName = $User.'Student Last Name'
        $ADUserParams = @{
            Name = "$FirstName $LastName"
            SamAccountName = $LoginName
            GivenName = $FirstName
            Initials = $User.'I'
            Surname = $LastName
            DisplayName = "$FirstName $($User.'I') $LastName"
            Description= $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name
            ScriptPath= "student.bat"
            UserPrincipalName = "$LoginName@academic.mydomain.k12.pa.us"
            EmailAddress = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            Company = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            EmployeeID = $User.'Other ID'
            HomeDirectory = "$FileServer\$LoginName"
            HomeDrive = "Z:"
            AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $AccountPass -AsPlainText -Force)
            Enabled = $True
            PasswordNeverExpires = $True
            CannotChangePassword = $True
            Path = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=mydomain,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                $User.'Grad Year',
                $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name)
            Server = $ADServer
            WhatIf = $False
        } # End ADUserParams

        Try {
            # Create new user.
            New-ADUser @ADUserParams -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write the error to the event log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName $EventLogName -Source $EventLogSources[0][1] -EntryType Warning -EventId $EventLogSources[0][0] -Message "Something went wrong with the creation of a new user, [$LoginName] : $_"
        }}}
```

***Second* attempt to get around the missing middle initial:**

```
# CSV file being imported.
$CsvFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\SampleData.csv"

# Import the contents of the CSV file.
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile"

# Loop through each line of the CSV, creating the user if the account doesn't already exist in AD.
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    [String]$LoginName = $User.'Stu Access Login'
    If (-Not (Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $LoginName})) {
        # Attempt #2 for Dealing with passwords for people without a middle initial.
        If ($User.I -ne "") {
            $AccountPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (
                '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
                    $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                    $User.I[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force

        } Else {
            $AccountPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (
                '{0}{1}#{2}' -f @(
                    $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                    $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force
        } # End If
        $FirstName = $User.'Student First Name'
        $LastName = $User.'Student Last Name'
        $ADUserParams = @{
            Name = "$FirstName $LastName"
            SamAccountName = $LoginName
            GivenName = $FirstName
            Initials = $User.'I'
            Surname = $LastName
            DisplayName = "$FirstName $($User.'I') $LastName"
            Description= $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name
            ScriptPath= "student.bat"
            UserPrincipalName = "$LoginName@academic.mydomain.k12.pa.us"
            EmailAddress = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            Company = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            EmployeeID = $User.'Other ID'
            HomeDirectory = "$FileServer\$LoginName"
            HomeDrive = "Z:"
            AccountPassword = $AccountPass
            Enabled = $True
            PasswordNeverExpires = $True
            CannotChangePassword = $True
            Path = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=mydomain,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                $User.'Grad Year',
                $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name)
            Server = $ADServer
            WhatIf = $False
        } # End ADUserParams

        Try {
            # Create new user.
            New-ADUser @ADUserParams -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write the error to the event log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName $EventLogName -Source $EventLogSources[0][1] -EntryType Warning -EventId $EventLogSources[0][0] -Message "Something went wrong with the creation of a new user, [$LoginName] : $_"
        }}}
```

If I run `ADUserParams` I can see the **AccountPassword** parameter is `System.Security.SecureString` so I figured that was a good thing.  So, what am I doing wrong?  I'd like to think either of those approaches would work - so long as I got everything correct.  However, as I said, I cannot authenticate unless I revert to the old code which cannot handle accounts without a middle initial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the order of things a bit wrong. You are creating `$AccountPass` using variables `$FirstName` and `$LastName` BEFORE you have defined them.

This should work

```
# CSV file being imported.
$CsvFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\SampleData.csv"

# Import the contents of the CSV file.
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "$CsvFile"

# Loop through each line of the CSV, creating the user if the account doesn't already exist in AD.
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    [String]$LoginName = $User.'Stu Access Login'
    If (-Not (Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $LoginName})) {
        $FirstName = $User.'Student First Name'
        $LastName = $User.'Student Last Name'

        # generate passwords
        If (!([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($User.I))) {
            # this person has an initial to use in the password
            $AccountPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (
                '{0}{1}{2}#{3}' -f @(
                    $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                    $User.I[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force
        } 
        Else {
            # this person does not have an initial to work with
            $AccountPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (
                '{0}{1}#{2}' -f @(
                    $FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(),
                    $LastName[0].ToString().ToLower(),
                    $User.'Other ID')) -AsPlainText -Force
        }

        $ADUserParams = @{
            Name = "$FirstName $LastName"
            SamAccountName = $LoginName
            GivenName = $FirstName
            Initials = $User.'I'
            Surname = $LastName
            DisplayName = "$FirstName $($User.'I') $LastName"
            Description= $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name
            ScriptPath= "student.bat"
            UserPrincipalName = "$LoginName@academic.mydomain.k12.pa.us"
            EmailAddress = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            Company = "$LoginName@mydomain.org"
            EmployeeID = $User.'Other ID'
            HomeDirectory = "$FileServer\$LoginName"
            HomeDrive = "Z:"
            AccountPassword = $AccountPass
            Enabled = $True
            PasswordNeverExpires = $True
            CannotChangePassword = $True
            Path = 'OU={0},OU=Students,OU={1},OU=accounts,DC=academic,DC=mydomain,DC=k12,DC=pa,DC=us' -f @(
                $User.'Grad Year',
                $SchoolCodes[$User.School].Name)
            Server = $ADServer
            WhatIf = $False
        } # End ADUserParams

        Try {
            # Create new user.
            New-ADUser @ADUserParams -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        Catch {
            # If there's an error, write the error to the event log.
            Write-EventLog -LogName $EventLogName -Source $EventLogSources[0][1] -EntryType Warning -EventId $EventLogSources[0][0] -Message "Something went wrong with the creation of a new user, [$LoginName] : $_"
        }}}
```

Comment: p.s. for combining the Displayname, I think this might do better: `"$FirstName $($User.'I') $LastName".Trim() -replace '\s+', ' '`. It avoids double spaces when there is no `$($User.'I')`

Comment: WOW!  This is exactly why a fresh set of eyes comes in handy.  I had been fighting with this for most of the day.  Cannot believe I didn't see that...  Thank you for the help.  And, yes, I was going to try to figure out a clean way to clean up the display name when the user doesn't have a middle initial so I'll give your idea a try as well.  Again, thanks!